# Question about the trace of covariance operators

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory

I've noticed what seems to be a disconnect in the ways some authors refer to the trace of a covariance operator:

Suppose $X$ is a mean zero random variable taking its value in a (possibly infinite dimensional) Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, with norm $\|\cdot\|$ and inner product $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$. The covariance operator of $X$ is defined as $C(y)= E[\langle X,y \rangle X]$.

The claim that I have seen often is that $trace(C) = E\|X\|^2$. I cannot understand why this is so, and it seems to rely on particular definitions of the trace that may depend on $\mathcal{H}$, and perhaps other properties of $X$.

Suppose for example that $X$ is a stochastic process $X: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ with sample paths in $L^2$. Then with $\mathcal{H}= L^2[0,1]$ and $C(t,s) = E(X(t)X(s))$,  $E\|X\|^2 = \int C(t,t)dt$. We might call $trace(C)= \int C(t,t)dt$.

On the other hand, for a positive definite linear operator $A$ acting on $\mathcal{H}$, $trace(A)= \sum_{\ell =1}^\infty \langle A(e_\ell), e_\ell \rangle$ for any basis $e_\ell$. With this definition, it does not seem clear that $trace(C)= \sum_{\ell =1}^\infty \langle C(e_\ell),e_\ell \rangle \stackrel{?}{=}    \int C(t,t)dt$. In general it seems like a somewhat delicate matter whether a kernel-integral operator $C$ has trace satisfying the formula $trace(C)= \int_0^1 C(t,t)dt.$ See e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/70969/when-is-an-integral-transform-trace-class

Is this easier than it looks? It $trace(C)= E\|X\|^2$ always? If $C$ is a kernel integral operator is $trace(C)= \int_0^1 C(t,t)dt$ always?

Comment: The indices are $s,t$, as $C$ is a scalar in H.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment, but in that example what I'm thinking is that $C$ is a kernel integral operator with kernel $C:[0,1]^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, i.e. $C(f)(t) = \int C(t,s)f(s)ds$. $t$ and $s$ in this case are values in $[0,1]$.

Comment: exactly, the trace thererfore is the sum (integral) of the diagonal $s=t$, just like a finite matrix.